# Is it possible to add custom interactive UI elements to EditText?

Tags: android, ios, view, android-edittext

A bit of context here.  I'm an iOS developer with no knowledge on Android development.

I need to know whether it's feasible in Android to embed custom interactive UI elements (in iOS that'd be a `UIView`) inside of `EditText`.

A library I found to do this in iOS is: https://github.com/vlas-voloshin/SubviewAttachingTextView

You can see a GIF in that link showcasing the kind of behavior I'm looking for.

Is there built in support, or any third party library I can use to achieve something similar in Android?

Answer (score 0):

in normal way this is not possible in android and we don't have any standard component or any library (that i know) for doing such a thing but we can create something similar to this (for this you should search about custom Views in android !) and also there is other way and easier way to achieve something similar to this is using the container layouts in android like LinearLayout and adding all your component to that container layout in run-time base on your text ! for example in your code you can dive in to your text and find tags like  or  and create appropriate view for your tag and add it to your container layout and at the end your layout looks like that gif wich is in your question ! and also in android we can show some basic html code in  textView